# Swift vars nested in functions - is any sort of garbage collection required?

Tags: swift, memory-management, nested

In Swift, in a scenario like this...

```
self.globalList //Large Array

function doStuff() {
   var nestedList = self.globalList.sorted()
   //do stuff with nestedList here
}

doStuff()
```

..Is the `nestedList` var automatically released/deleted from memory after `doStuff()` has been executed? Sorry if this question's very novice. I'm reasonably new to Swift and I just want to be sure I'm not leaving large memory chewers floating around my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no garbage collection in swift, and even in Objective-C it was replaced by [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). I would recommend to study it, but to answer your question, ARC will take care of nestedList, so it will release it in the end of the function.

And I would suggest to read that as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html